# Will window.open() mothod work on mobile web?

Tags: jquery

Will `window.open()` method work on mobile web? I tried using it but it does not work.

```
$('#open-popup').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'width=300,height=200');
});
```

Comment: Are trying to open in a new tab ? if so, it may have the same behavior as a desktop browser and you probably won't be able to do that. Otherwise, yes, will work. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yes it actually has to be opened in a new window.